# Issue with R shiny's DT::dataTableOutput() forcing unnecessary reactivity updates

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I'm working on an R shiny app structured like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

# global function
make_data = function(input){
  data.frame(x = input$x, `x_times_2` = input$x*2)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("x", label = "Set x:", min = 1, value = 7, max = 10),
  # Recalculates continuously, bad!
  dataTableOutput("dtab"),
  # Recalculates when inputs change, good!
  # tableOutput("tab")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  reactive_data = reactive({
    print("Recalculating Data")
    make_data(reactiveValuesToList(input))
  })

  output$tab = renderTable({
    reactive_data()  
  })

  output$dtab = renderDataTable({
    reactive_data()  
  })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

My problem is that `dataTableOutput("dtab")` forces continuous recalculation of `reactive_data` whereas `tableOutput("tab")` (correctly) only recalculates when inputs change. Can someone help me understand why this happens?

I need to be able to pass inputs into a global function that makes a data frame which I then need to display. I want to use `dataTableOutput()` for the customization that `DT` offers but need it to only recalculate when any input is changed.

Comment: As an update, I found out that the `dataTableOutput()` and `renderDataTable()` pair create a ton of parameters in the server's `input`. One of those must be changing constantly which is picked up by `reactiveValuesToList(input)`. That might mean what I'm trying to do is impossible?

Comment: My theory is that some of the DT generated inputs are first created and then later assigned a value. When they are assigned a value, `reactiveValuesToList(input)` changes triggering a recalculation and the table to be recreated...a vicious cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation, you could use `eventReactive()` instead of `reactive`.  Try this

```
  reactive_data = eventReactive(input$x, {
    print("Recalculating Data")
    make_data(reactiveValuesToList(input))
  })
```

Comment: `isolate()` doesn't work because it prevents the `reactive_data` from ever reacting to changes in inputs. Thus the data never updates when it is used.

Comment: `eventReactive()` is on the right track, but I want it to update if any input is changed. I have a lot of them and listing them out isn't really viable. My main question though is why I'm seeing the difference in behavior of `tableOutput()` and `dataTableOutput()`. I expect them to interact with reactive data in the same way.